# Is it possible to set e the initial-select value of a recursive CTE query with a parameter?

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression

Using this self-referencing table:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTRY (
    ID integer NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID integer,
    ... other columns ...
)
```

There are many top-level rows (with PARENT_ID = NULL) that can have 0 to several levels of child rows, forming a graph like this:

```
(1, NULL, 'A'),
(2, 1, 'B'),
(3, 2, 'C'),
(4, 3, 'D'),
(5, 4, 'E'),
(6, NULL, 'one'),
(7, 6, 'two'),
(8, 7, 'three'),
(9, 6, 'four'),
(10, 9, 'five'),
(11, 10, 'six');
```

I want to write a query that would give me the subgraph (all related rows ***in both directions***) for a given row, for instance (just showing the ID values):

```
ID = 3: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ID = 6: (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
ID = 7: (6, 7, 8)
ID = 10: (6, 9, 10, 11)
```

It's similar to the query in [§3.3 Queries against a Graph](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) of the SQLite documentation, for returning a graph from any of its nodes:

```
WITH RECURSIVE subtree(x) AS (
       SELECT 3
       UNION
       SELECT e1.ID x FROM ENTRY e1 JOIN subtree ON e1.PARENT_ID = subtree.x
       UNION
       SELECT e2.PARENT_ID x FROM ENTRY e2 JOIN subtree ON e2.ID = subtree.x
    )
SELECT x FROM subtree
LIMIT 100;
```

... with 3 as the anchor / initial-select value.
This particular query works fine in DBeaver. The sqlite version available in db-fiddle gives a circular reference error, but [this nested CTE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oV6zKmLAsBoho9Km7URyFg/1) gives the same result in db-fiddle.

However, I can only get this to work when the initial value is hard-coded in the query. I can't find any mention of *how to supply that initial-select value as a parameter.*

I'd think it should be straightforward. Maybe the case of having more than one top-level row is very unusual, or I'm overlooking something blindingly obvious?

Any suggestions?

Comment: added example data for clarity, and an (alternative) db-fiddle query to show what I mean

Comment: SQLite does not support stored procedures or user defined functions where you could pass a parameter. What you want to do can be done in the app that accesses the db if you use a prepared statement with a ? placeholder for the parameter, but can't be done with SQLite only.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't know that. I'll go with the prepared statement option, then 

Answer (score 0):

As **forpas** points out above, SQLite doesn't support passing parameters to stored/user defined functions.

Using a placeholder in the prepared statement from the calling code is a good alternative.